# Sardines as a snack

Tags: fish, snacks, sardines

We like to eat sardines with crackers for a lunchtime snack. What are some good sauces and toppings for sardines?

Comment: Perhaps this should be community wiki

Answer (score 4):

Fish tacos!

- 1 avocado
- 1 tomato
- small white onion
- cumin
- juice of 1 lime
- salt
- sardines
- cilantro

Fry the sardines in their own oil for a minute (this is optional), add the cumin, fry 30 more seconds, dump into a bowl, and add the other ingredients, finely chopped, mix well.

Takes about 2 minutes. Delicious.

Answer (score 2):

We like a mix of sauce of ketchup and Goldens honey mustard, with a side of tomato avocado and cheese.

Answer (score 2):

You should try (if the sardines are canned with oil):

french bread + some onions chopped + sardines and season with salt + lemon.

Answer (score 1):

Sardines, being so salty and fishy, need something to soften the taste. I find hard-boiled egg to be an excellent accompaniment, with this in mind.

For a very simple open-faced sandwich, ideally on some dark-grain bread, top a layer of sardine filets with slices of hard-boiled egg. Lightly salted and peppered with a little bit of red onion, as a garnish, this is a really nice way to enjoy the fish. This is a [really common snack](http://kuduvkoeraomanik.blogspot.com/2010/03/puhas-klassika.html), out here in Estonia.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy is to sprinkle with [berbere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berbere), which is actually easy to make at home (though it requires blending a lot of spices).

[Old Bay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Bay_Seasoning) would be another fine topping.